# How can I reach the value which iterator is pointing at?

Tags: c++

I have a std::list of some type, for example `list<FILE>`. I need to for-each access all values stored in it, for example:

```
    list<FILE>::iterator iter;

    for(iter = Preferences::OpenFD.begin(); iter != Preferences::OpenFD.end(); iter++)
    {
        fclose(iter);
    }
```

This doesn't work because iter is not a FILE. How can I reach the value which this iter is pointing at?

Comment: `list<FILE>` is wrong, because you have no way of constructing a `FILE` object.  `fopen` returns a `FILE*`.

Comment: ok, it's wrong, but maybe if you explained to me how to do it correctly, would be far more useful than just downvoting the question, which, indeed is more simple...

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but you might *think* about what everyone is telling you and stop expecting to be spoonfed.  This problem is very simple and you've already been given plenty of clues.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a dereference operator:

```
fclose(*iter);
//     ^
```

Note also, `fclose` expects a `FILE*`, not `FILE`.

With C++11 you could use range-based for:

```
for(auto& elem: Preferences::OpenFD)
    fclose(elem);
```

Or you could also use `std::for_each`:

```
std::for_each(Preferences::OpenFD.begin(), Preferences::OpenFD.end(), fclose);
```

Comment: fclose(*iter) doesn't work either, but I suppose there is no way to do this using list

Comment: _"fclose(*iter) doesn't work either"_ - I already told why: _"fclose expects a `FILE*`, not `FILE`"_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference the iterator to access the `FILE` object:

```
fclose(*it);
```